# Полезные микросхемы

Tags: микроконтроллеры, электроника

Есть микросхемы на все случаи жизни? ну или если переформулировать то - микросхемы которые зачастую используются.

Например:

`NE555, ULN2003, SN74HC165N`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по программированию

Answer (score 3):

Самые популярные:

- **555** - таймер
- **LM324** - относится к операционным усилителям общего применения
- **78XX** - линейка интегральных регуляторов
- **74XX** - логика (серия интелектуальных микросхем)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы имеете ввиду универсальность, то лучший ответ - микроконтроллеры.

- **PIC**
- **AVR, AVR32**

Если же нет, то

- **555**
- различного рода матрицы транзисторов, как например КР198НТ1А
- как было сказано выше 74xx, 78xx

и так далее.

P.s. Вопрос не по теме. У Stack Exchange Inc есть отдельный сайт по радиотехнике